# What indexes should be created for this MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, query-optimization, database-indexes

If I have the following query, what indexes could be created to speed it up?

```
SELECT `residentials`.* 
FROM `residentials` 
WHERE 
  (is_active = 1) AND 
  (
    (created_at > '2012-02-20 20:51:56' OR modified > '2012-02-20 20:51:56') AND 
    list_price >= 229000 AND 
    list_price <= 311000 AND 
    square_feet >= '1223' AND 
    square_feet <= '1654' AND 
    property_type IN ('commercial','condo','detached','house','multi','rowtownhouse','semidetached') AND
    (zip LIKE '%19147%')
  )
ORDER BY list_price DESC
```

FYI, this query is being generated by Rails so I don't have full control over how it is constructed.

Using EXPLAIN yields the following:

id = 1

select_type = SIMPLE

table = residentials

type = range

possible_keys = index_residentials_on_list_price,index_residentials_on_property_style,index_residentials_on_square_feet,index_residentials_on_modified,index_residentials_on_is_active,index_residentials_on_is_active_and_board_id,index_residentials_is_active_board_id_list_price_property_type,index_residentials_on_is_active_and_created_at_and_modified,dates_and_type,dates_type_price,board_price_type_zip,board_price_type_zip_mls

key = index_residentials_on_list_price

key_len = 6

ref = NULL

rows = 209272

Extra = Using where

Comment: A couple of suggestion for speed (using EXPLAIN as shown below to see what helps) - try using BETWEEN for the > and < conditions.  Also the zip `LIKE` will be performance heavy.  I would try the query with and without it and with/without an index on zip.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try :

```
EXPLAIN SELECT `residentials`.* 
FROM `residentials` 
WHERE 
  (is_active = 1) AND 
  (
    (created_at > '2012-02-20 20:51:56' OR 
     modified > '2012-02-20 20:51:56') AND 
     list_price >= 229000 AND 
     list_price <= 311000 AND 
     square_feet >= '1223' AND 
     square_feet <= '1654' AND 
     property_type IN ('commercial','condo','detached','house','multi','rowtownhouse','semidetached') AND
     (zip LIKE '%19147%')
  )
ORDER BY list_price DESC
```

Comment: +1 yes, do this, explain (plan) was created for just this purpose.  I fyou are still stuck please post the results.  Otherwise all the other suggestions you see are going to be stabbing in the dark.

Comment: I've added the results of EXPLAIN above if that helps

Answer (score 0):

The order of the columns really important for indexes, try:

```
is_active, created_at, modified, list_price, square_feet, property_type
```